# moving triple boot setup to larger SSD

Tags: windows, dual-boot, dd, ssd

I currently have a triple boot setup on my laptop, with Arch linux, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Unfortunately, my SSD is only 256 GB and is suffering quite a bit now with low space on the windows C drive. I am looking to buy a new SSD to replace my current one and would like to move everything to the larger drive. I dont think my laptop has a second slot so replace the drive might be my only choice.

I know that I can probably use `dd` to clone my current SSD but I need to expand my partitions as well. What are my options for this?

My current partition scheme looks like this:

256 MB - EFI partition

30 GB - Arch root partition (`/`)

30 GB - Arch /home partition

50 GB - Windows C drive

100 GB - shared NTFS partition amongst all OSs to store my data

28 GB - Ubuntu partition

Is my best option to just clone the entire SSD first and then expand and move each partition one by one?
Im sure this would also affect my bootloader settings as well, particularly with windows. I am using rEFInd so any tips would be appreciated.

While I do this, is it also possible to rearrange the partitions? Maybe by copying the partitions one by one. This isnt a requirement for me but I may rearrange the partitions while changing disk if possible

Thanks in advance